# How to draw a cushion like rectangle in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to draw a cushion like rectangle in processing like the pic shown. Is there any tricky way to use "light" to realize this? Does anyone have any idea about it? Thanks!
[image]

Pic reference: http://philogb.github.io/blog/2009/02/05/cushion-treemaps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called a **radial gradient**.

There are a number of ways to do it. One way would be to simply draw a bunch of circles. Here is a small example:

```
size(200, 200);
for(float diameter = 255; diameter > 0; diameter--){
  noStroke();
  fill(0, 255-diameter, 0); 
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, diameter, diameter);
}
```

You'll also have to limit your drawings to a rectangle shape. You might do that using the `createGraphics()` function to create a buffer, then draw the gradient to the buffer, then draw the buffer to the screen.

You should really [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. First create a sketch that shows a simple gradient. Then create a sketch that uses a buffer. Get those both working by themselves before you combine them into one sketch. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and suggestions! The example works great. And I will try out what you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another common method for implementing a collection of radial gradients of the type shown (a treemap) is:

1. create or acquire a single fairly high resolution image asset with a (jpeg/png) -- https://www.google.com/search?q=radial+gradient+box&tbm=isch
2. load the image
3. as you draw your boxes
4. optionally use `tint()` to tint the image green, red, etc. This works best with a grayscale source image.
5. scale your source image to the correct size for each box using the 5-argument `image(img, x1, y1, x2, y2)`